# How can I solve this 'substring not found' error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I want a user to input his name and last name and then this two words will replace every second letter with each other.

```py
def translate(ime,prez):
    translated_i = ""
    translated_p = ""
    if len(ime) >= len(prez):
        for letter in prez:
            if prez.index(letter) != 0:
                translated_p = translated_p + ime[prez.index(letter)]
                if prez.index(letter) >= len(prez)-1:
                    translated_i = translated_i + ime[prez.index(letter):]
                else:
                    translated_i = translated_i + prez[ime.index(letter)]
        else:
            translated_p = translated_p + letter
            translated_i = translated_i + ime[prez.index(letter)]
    elif len(prez) > len(ime):
        for letter in ime:
            if ime.index(letter) != 0:
                translated_i = translated_i + prez[ime.index(letter)]
                if prez.index(letter) >= len(prez)-1:
                    translated_p = translated_p + prez[ime.index(letter):]
                else:
                    translated_p = translated_p + ime[prez.index(letter)]
            else:
                translated_i = translated_i + letter
                translated_p = translated_p + prez[ime.index(letter)]
    return translated_i + " " + translated_p
    x = input("Name: ")
    y = input("Last name: ")

    print(translate(x,y))
```

But there is an error saying: 'ValueError: substring not found'

Comment: Please add your stacktrace.

Comment: Please, always say where your error is. Usually people just post those 100 lines of code and people are supposed to find the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, `index` function raises `ValueError` if the substring is not found.
So instead of checking `if ime.index(letter) != 0` you can wrap your code inside `try/except` block. For example:

```
try:
    letter_index = ime.index(letter)
    # your logic if substring found
except ValueError as ex:
    # logic if substring not found
```

Answer (score 0):

its working for me

code:

```
def translate(ime,prez):
    translated_i = ""
    translated_p = ""
    if len(ime) >= len(prez):
        for letter in prez:
            if prez.index(letter) != 0:
                translated_p = translated_p + ime[prez.index(letter)]
                if prez.index(letter) >= len(prez)-1:
                    translated_i = translated_i + ime[prez.index(letter):]
                else:
                    translated_i = translated_i + prez[ime.index(letter)]
        else:
            translated_p = translated_p + letter
            translated_i = translated_i + ime[prez.index(letter)]
    elif len(prez) > len(ime):
        for letter in ime:
            if ime.index(letter) != 0:
                translated_i = translated_i + prez[ime.index(letter)]
                if prez.index(letter) >= len(prez)-1:
                    translated_p = translated_p + prez[ime.index(letter):]
                else:
                    translated_p = translated_p + ime[prez.index(letter)]
            else:
                translated_i = translated_i + letter
                translated_p = translated_p + prez[ime.index(letter)]
    return translated_i + " " + translated_p

x = input("Name: ")
y = input("Last name: ")

print(translate(x,y))
```

ss:
[image]

Comment: Try with 6 letters in name and 5 letters in last name

Answer (score 0):

I copy-pasted your code, and besides the wrong indentation, everything was right. I suggest you fix the indentation to:

```
def translate(ime,prez):
    translated_i = ""
    translated_p = ""
    if len(ime) >= len(prez):
        for letter in prez:
            if prez.index(letter) != 0:
                translated_p = translated_p + ime[prez.index(letter)]
                if prez.index(letter) >= len(prez)-1:
                    translated_i = translated_i + ime[prez.index(letter):]
                else:
                    translated_i = translated_i + prez[ime.index(letter)]
        else:
            translated_p = translated_p + letter
            translated_i = translated_i + ime[prez.index(letter)]
    elif len(prez) > len(ime):
        for letter in ime:
            if ime.index(letter) != 0:
                translated_i = translated_i + prez[ime.index(letter)]
                if prez.index(letter) >= len(prez)-1:
                    translated_p = translated_p + prez[ime.index(letter):]
                else:
                    translated_p = translated_p + ime[prez.index(letter)]
            else:
                translated_i = translated_i + letter
                translated_p = translated_p + prez[ime.index(letter)]
    return translated_i + " " + translated_p
x = input("Name: ")
y = input("Last name: ")

print(translate(x,y))
```

And copy-paste it to another file. If you get another error and youre using some text editor than IDLE, try the code in IDLE.